# Binding not updating before all tasks are finished

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, async-await

I have a ListView with a data template that contains my user control. This user control has a dependency property "`MyObject`" as well as an Image component that is bound to a property of "`MyObject`" of type `AsyncLazy<BitmapImage>`. The image is asynchronously downloaded in the background and returned (while also invoking an event). The invoked event starts the animation on my Image component to fade in and show the downloaded image.

## The Problem

At first this performed as expected, **but if images were downloaded at significanlty different times, the animation still started - but the images were not displayed until all images finished downloading** - causing some images to just pop in - because the fade in animation already started for them before they were loaded.

## A step further...

I went a step further and added a method for each user control that loads some data from a website in the background - it's rather long-running, so I simply start the Task when user control is initialized and that's it. The task should run in the background and store the result to a property of "`MyObject`" when finished **without** waiting for it.

But for some reason - the images don't start downloading until the above-mentionted Task finishes.

## Code

### XAML of my user control

```
<Image x:Name="mainImage" Source="{Binding ImageMedium.Value.Result, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

### Properties within "MyObject"

```
public AsyncLazy<BitmapImage> ImageMedium { get; }
public List<MyEntry> Entries { get; private set; }
```

### User Control Initialization

```
 public void Init()
 {
      MyObject.GetEntries(); 
      // this long-running task should just run in the BG without waiting for it
      // ...
 }
```

### "GetEntries" method

```
public async Task GetEntries()
{
      var t = await Task.Run(() => Do some work... );                       
      Entries = t; // store result to a MyObject property
}
```

### Getting the image

```
ImageMedium = new AsyncLazy<BitmapImage>(() =>
{
      var data = GetImage(ImageSize.Medium); // normal long-running method
      ImageLoaded?.Invoke(data, ImageSize.Medium); // event that starts animation
      return data;
});
```

### Animation

```
control.MyObject.ImageLoaded += (img, s) =>
{
    // start animation when Image is loaded
    control.UIContext.Send(async (a) => {
           await Task.Delay(500);
           DoubleAnimation dan1 = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7));
           control.mainImage.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, dan1);
     }, null);
};
```

I also tried implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notifying the change together with the invoking of the event - but solved nothing.

EDIT: Upon further testing, it seems the Images DO start downloading before the long-running task finishes - but the downloading is delayed by about 20-30 seconds before it actually starts.

Comment: When an image that's been downloaded is fading in, you want to wait for it to be completed, before starting any new animation for any other images which may have been downloaded in that period, and that animation then needs to start from the "beginning" to fade in the next downloaded image, right ? (in which case you'll need a From)

Comment: The ListView contains multiple instances of my user controls. Each user control contains one image that is downloaded. So the animation just needs to go off once - when the image is downloaded. And never again.

Comment: Do you create/use a new storyboard on each of your UserControl instances ?

Comment: I just edited my question and added the animation code that I used. And yes, this code is used on each of my UserControl instances.